# Show that $Z(t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} (1-t)B\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right) & x \in [0,1) \\ 1 & \, t=1 \\ \end{array} \right. $ is a Brownian bridge

Tags: brownian-motion, brownian-bridge

Let $W_t$ be a standard Brownian motion and let
$$Z(t) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
(1-t)B\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right) & t \in [0,1) \\
1 & \, t=1 \\
\end{array}
\right. $$
I don't get why $Z$ is a Brownian Bridge. I have to prove that $Cov(Z(t),Z(s))=\min\{s,t\}-st$ for all $s,t\in(0,1)$, and $E(Z(t))=0$ and that $Z(t)$ is a continuous Gauß process. The first two thinks a trivial but I don't get why $Z(t)$ is continuous for $t=1$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving $ X_t = W_t - \int_0^t \frac{X_s}{1 - s} \, ds$ is the Brownian Bridge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4774340/proving-x-t-w-t-int-0t-fracx-s1-s-ds-is-the-brownian-bridge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the
[law of large numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099655/law-of-large-numbers-for-brownian-motion-direct-proof-using-l2-convergence) for Brownian motion
$$
\lim_{s\to\infty}\frac{B_s}{s}=0\,.
$$
Therefore
$$
\lim_{t\to 1}\left(t\frac{B_\frac t{1-t}}{\frac t{1-t}}\right)=\lim_{t\to 1}(1-t)B_\frac t{1-t}=0\,.
$$